# NPN BJT linear region operation

Tags: transistors, bjt

I am trying to simulate a 2N2222 in the direct active region.
The calculations of \$I_B\$ and \$I_C\$ currents work for me, but in the end when I do \$I_C/I_B\$ I get a \$h_{FE}\$=21 which is not there in the datasheet ... it is just below the minimum indicated.

What am I doing wrong?

[image]

[image]

Comment: The datasheet for a 2M2222A transistor show hFE ONLY when the Vce is 10V. It shows an hFE of only 10 when the transistor is deeply saturated with a saturated Vce of less than 0.3V like with most transistors.

Comment: What is the reason for V2?

Comment: Remove V2, it's plain wrong. You want to *measure* voltage there. That way you are *imposing* 0.4 V

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Edit:** I just noticed voltage source V2 (a bit obscured by the info panels), and it makes no sense to me why it's there. All it does is fix the collector potential to 400mV, rendering the transistor impotent. It may be the only reason your circuit doesn't do what you expect, so remove it. Having said that, my treatise below is still a propos.

---

It is notoriously difficult to keep a "common-emitter" BJT operating in its "linear" region, without feedback or some other mitigating measure, for a couple of reasons:

1. Each transistor, even those from the same batch, have slightly different characteristics, such as \$h_{fe}\$ (often called \$\beta\$, which is how I will refer to current gain) and \$V_{BE}\$ vs. \$I_B\$.
2. Changes in temperature cause a large shift in \$V_{BE}\$ vs. \$I_B\$, meaning that after you've carefully calculated your component values to have exactly the right base current to achieve the perfect collector potential, you move your circuit into a different room, or just breathe on it, and it doesn't work any more.

That said, if you are only simulating the setup, then neither of these are a problem, since transistor characteristics are well defined, and temperature doesn't change.

In your simulated experiment, your first consideration should be the maximum and minimum collector potentials you can expect, which are +5V and 0V, corresponding to the transistor being completely "off" and completely "on" (saturated), respectively.

Corresponding to those extremes, are the maximum and minimum collector currents \$I_C\$ that can be achieved (that is, the current through R2). When the transistor is saturated (fully on), its collector will be almost a direct short-circuit to emitter (ground in this "common emitter" scenario, 0V), in which case collector potential \$V_C\$ is close to zero. Then the voltage across R2 is almost the full 5V supply, so that by Ohm's law:

$$ I_{C(MAX)} = \frac{5V}{80.6\Omega} = 62mA $$

In the situation where the transistor is fully off, collector current obviously drops to zero:

$$ I_{C(MIN)} = 0A $$

In other words, collector potential \$V_C\$ and collector current \$I_C\$ are bounded as follows:

$$ 0 \le V_C \le +5.0V $$
$$ 0 \le I_C \le 62mA $$

<sub>Note: In reality collector-to-emitter potential difference \$V_{CE}\$ for a saturated transistor is closer to 0.2V, not zero. So minimum collector potential and maximum collector current are closer to \$V_{C(MIN)}=+0.2V\$ and \$I_{C(MAX)}=\frac{5-0.2}{80.6}=60mA\$ respectively:
$$ +0.2V \le V_C \le +5.0V $$
$$ 0mA \le I_C \le 60mA $$</sub>

In your own circuit, as shown, \$V_C = 400mV\$ and \$I_C = 57mA\$. This is perilously close to saturation, and with this collector-to-emitter potential difference of only 0.4V, you are operating the transistor in a region far away from what you might call "linear". At this extreme, \$\beta\$ falls off very quickly.

If it's not clear why, think about this: If the transistor is saturated, collector current is already at a maximum or 62mA. Further increases in base current cannot possibly result in an increase of collector current, and therefore current *gain* (which is the ratio of *change* in collector current to *change* in base current) becomes *zero*. Likewise, in cut-off, where collector current is already zero, reduction of base current can't possibly result in collector current dropping any further, so gain drops to zero.

Therefore, the datasheet's quoted value for current gain \$\beta\$ (\$h_{fe}\$; last time I say that) is only valid when the transistor is in a state somewhere *between* saturation and cut-off. That is, somewhere near the middle of those extremes we defined above.

The [2N2222's datasheet](https://www.farnell.com/datasheets/296640.pdf) tells us that \$\beta\$ could be as low as 50, or as high as 300. That's a lot of uncertainty. Clearly it's highly variable depending on factors such as temperature, collector current etc. If you know the exact value of \$\beta\$ for your particular device, as you do in this simulation, this is not a problem.

If I knew that \$\beta=100\$, then I could say with certainty that as long as I keep collector potential half way between 0V and +5V, (with corresponding collector current being half way between zero and 62mA), then this value \$\beta=100\$ can be used in my calculations.

Let's assume \$\beta=100\$. You'll have to find the exact value used by your simulated 2N2222 model.

We know that collector current can range from zero to 62mA, so I will set my target \$I_C\$ at half of that, \$I_C = 31mA\$, to keep the transistor well out of saturation or cut-off, right in the middle in fact. That will also place my collector potential half way, at about \$V_C=+2.5V\$.

I'll calculate the base current \$I_B\$ that would correspond to that collector current:

$$ I_B = \frac{I_C}{\beta} = \frac{31mA}{100} = 310\mu A $$

Now I'll find a base resistance R1 that would pass this current. I need to make an assumption, that the base-emitter junction has \$V_{BE}=0.7V\$ across it (since it's essentially just a forward-biased diode). That means the voltage across R1 will be 0.7V less than the full 5V supply (see the VM1 in the schematic below). That is, by KVL, the voltage \$V_{R1}\$ across R1 is:

$$  V_{R1} = 5V - 0.7V = 4.3V $$

Consequently, by Ohm's law, the necessary value of R1 to pass current \$I_B = 310\mu A\$ is:

$$ R_1 = \frac{V_{R1}}{I_B} = \frac{4.3V}{310\mu A} = 13.9k\Omega $$

The resulting circuit looks like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fhcakB.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

As you can see, the state of affairs is close to the calculated targets, but not exact. The reason is that we estimated \$V_{BE}=0.70V\$, when in fact it seems to be closer to 0.67V. This means that base current is slightly higher than we predicted.

\$V_{BE}\$ is a highly variable parameter for various reasons, a fact that makes it very difficult to predict ahead of time the biasing state of such a circuit.

To recap:

- Your transistor is near saturation, and consequently \$\beta\$ is far from its advertised value. A similar state of affairs occurs near cut-off.
- You chose resistor values which do not correspond to the simulator's idea of the value of \$\beta\$, which in turn differs from the datasheet's (uncertain) claim for that value. You seem to have underestimated \$\beta\$, leading to more collector current than you expected, and causing the transistor to nearly saturate.

Comment: There is still something I don't understand. I give an example:
If I want an Ic=200mA when Ib=2mA .. the bjt needs beta=100. So Rb=(5-0.7)/Ib=4.3/10mA=430.
In the datasheet of the 2N222, beta=[100 .. 300] when Ic=150mA and Vce=10V ...
I want beta=100 ... how do I get that? What calculations do I do?

I did like this: with Vcc=12V .. Vcc-80.6*Ic-Vce=0 --> 12-80.6*200mA-10=-14V! It's not 0 :(
Either I'm doing the calculations wrong, or I have to change something I have to change something in this equality to make it equal zero (e.g. I try to change Vcc, or I try to change transistors etc.)

Comment: @Kal Sadly, you don't get to control \$\beta\$, that's up to the transistor. What you *can* control is base current. When you say you want \$I_C=200mA\$ and \$I_B=2mA\$, you are implying that you wish to somehow *force* \$\beta=\frac{200}{2}=100\$, which is not how this works. I'll say it again, you don't get to choose \$\beta\$. You *can* choose a transistor with \$\beta\approx 100\$, but for any given transistor that you already have, its \$\beta\$ is already "set in stone", so to speak.

Comment: In several theory exercises on bjt I have seen, β was set at a certain value and asked to find Rb, Ib etc.
So I didn't know I couldn't control it (this is the first time I have tried to simulate a bjt).
When you say "You can choose a transistor with β≈100",
it seems to me that you have to fulfil certain conditions in order to have a bjt with a certain β. Correct me if I am wrong, in the datasheet I read that the 2N222 provides a β=75 when Ic=10mA and Vce=10V. Are these perhaps the only conditions to be met to get that value?

Comment: @KaleM, Ah, I see, yes it's true that \$\beta\$ varies somewhat with \$I_C\$, and I suppose it *may* be possible (with a real transistor) to start by finding that particular \$I_C\$, where \$\beta=100\$, but I can't say it's considered good practice, or even if simulators model the transistor in that way. Give me a moment to see if at least CircuitLab does...

Comment: @KaleM I spent a few brain cells to conclude that the simulator does indeed model \$\beta\$ changing with \$I_C\$, but this is to do with "admittance" and the "Early voltage". I'm afraid those are two terms which I can't explain here. In the meantime I'm going to stick with "you can't, and shouldn't, try to control \$\beta\$". Exercises specify \$\beta\$ because it's an intrinsic property of a specific BJT, not because they're somehow in control of it. 2N2222 has \$\beta\$ different from 2N3904, BC547 is different again, and so on.

Comment: @KaleM I must admit, I haven't ever come across a question like this about the behaviour of a BJT, and never really thought about it. I've always approached problems where I have to choose \$I_C\$ or \$I_B\$ given some transistor-defined \$\beta\$. It's an interesting twist you raise, but I don't feel it's a useful approach, or one I'm qualified to talk about.

Comment: I have a further doubt:

Saying ""drive on the collector of a bjt a current Ic=[Ic(min) .. Ic(max)] that varies according to how I vary the Vbe=[Vbe(min) .. Vbe(max)]"" (biasing the base with voltage divider)       is the same as saying ""drive on the collector of a bjt a current Ic=[Ic(min) .. Ic(max)] that varies according to how I vary the current on the base Ib[Ib(min) .. Ib(max)]"" ??  Or are they two completely different things??

Comment: You asked, "I want beta=100 ... how do I get that?". You buy 1000 transistors and measure the hFE on all them. You might find one with a beta of 100 if you do not allow its temperature to change. We use negative feedback then any beta number or any base-emitter voltage difference works fine.

Comment: @KaleM Base potential and base current are intimately related, by the diode equation. You change one, you change the other, so there's certainly a \$V_{BE(MIN)}\$ that corresponds to cut-off, and a  \$V_{BE(MAX)}\$ that corresponds to saturation. The problem is extreme variability in those thresholds with temperature, and between devices, making it pointless to try to predict them. In this common emitter setup base current is much easier to predict and control, and \$\beta\$ stays fairly constant, so that's our focus. Other configurations have other concerns.

Answer (score 5):

The biggest problem is that you're using the wrong current for your calculation - the current flowing through R2 isn't the collector current. It just flows from one voltage source (V3) into the other (V2). You could just as well delete the transistor and the current through the resistor still wouldn't change.

Another problem is that you're not actually operating the transistor in the linear region - you're operating it in the saturation region, or at least very close to it.

The datasheet specifies the transistor's current gain for Vce=10V and Vce=1V, while you're only operating it at Vce=0.4V. The closer you get to full saturation, the lower the transistor's gain will be.

Give it more collector-emitter voltage, or alternatively, run it at higher base current to compensate for the lower gain. You should also take a look at figure 4 (Collector Saturation Region) in the transistor's [datasheet](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/p2n2222a-d.pdf), which shows its behavior at or near saturation.

Answer (score 5):

You have the transistor biased into saturation. With an 80.6\$\Omega\$ collector resistor the current for \$V_{CE}\$ of 2.5 V (Q point = 1/2 Vcc) would be 31 mA, you have nearly twice that.

I'm not really sure what V2 is in your simulation. When I put the circuit into LTspice without it I get an \$I_C\$ of 61 mA and \$V_{CE}\$ of 95 mV, so it's in saturation. A base resistor of 25k gives me an \$I_C\$ of around 31 mA and \$I_C\$ / \$I_B\$ is 184, more like what you're looking for.

When calculating the base resistor you would take your desired \$I_C\$ divided by the expected beta to get a rough base current, then find the resistance by V / I, using 5 V - 0.7 V for the voltage across the base resistor. This will get you in the ballpark but beta and \$V_{BE}\$ will vary from device to device so you need to adjust the calculated value by trial and error. You should do some research on transistor biasing, this is the simplest way of biasing and there are much better ones that make the beta and \$V_{BE}\$ not matter so much.

Answer (score 4):

Simon Fitch (especially) and others already explained why you don't get the results you are expecting (the BJT is nearly saturated and β is not what you expect to be).

However, I'd like to focus on a slightly different issue here: the fact that your exercise belongs to a class of "idealized" exercises that don't reflect how a design should be carried out.

The main issue here is that β is actually an unknown, being only bounded by very lax specifications (max and min values).

First of all, β is not a constant, but depends heavily on temperature and, less dramatically, on Ic and Vce (and also frequency, but we are not dealing with fast varying signals here). In particular, when Vce starts getting low, less than a ~0.6V, the BJT starts saturating and the linear relation between Ib and Ic cease to be true. Said another way, β is no longer constant, not even approximately (as we assume in the active region).

The constness of β is essentially a "lie to children" thing that is approximately true only in the active region *at constant temperature*.

On top of all these issues, the actual value of β varies wildly from one specimen to another of the same model. Said in other words, the fabrication tolerances are horrible. These are expressed by the two columns "min" and "max" in the datasheet. Often manufacturers only specify a guaranteed minimum β *at some given conditions* (given Ic, temperature and Vce), but you can easily get double or triple that value for some specimen of a given part!

All this means that any design that relies on a given value of β is a very bad design. The only designs that actually work reliably are those where you can either *neglect* the actual β value or assume only *a minimum guaranteed value* in the conditions you are expecting your circuit to work within.

Often, especially for non-critical circuits, this guaranteed minimum β is assumed to be 100, which is a common rule of thumb for low-frequency low-power BJTs intended to work at reasonable ambient temperatures with a current in the range between about (very roughly) 1mA and 10mA. That assumes also that the BJT is well within the active region, i.e. its Vce never drops below about (very roughly) 1V.

As you can see, lots of rules of thumbs and never an exact value of β, so even if you have a circuit with a given Ib, you can't really determine Ic using β. Usually you choose your quiescent Ic to be in the range 1-10mA, then go on determining other circuit parameters *after you choose a suitable biasing technique*, which almost always requires some form of negative feedback to make the gain ***of the circuit*** (usually an amplifier, if you are working in the active region) independent from the gain ***of the BJT (i.e. β)***.

The simplest way to bias a BJT reliably is therefore to introduce an emitter resistor (that gives the negative feedback) and drive the base using a voltage divider, so you have the classic 4-resistor biasing topology (base divider + collector resistor + emitter resistor) shown by PStechPaul in his answer.

Comment: Surprisingly, this post has been given zero points so far, although it is - in my opinion - the only one that correctly describes the (secondary) role of the base current in setting the operating point.
Question: Which physical relationship is primarily responsible for the uncertainties in setting the operating point? Answer: Ic=Is*[exp(Vbe/Vt)-1]. Here it becomes clear that the current Ic is determined by Vbe only - and the base current is to be considered as a by-product (as a small part of the emitter current).

Comment: Continued: The strong temperature dependence of the current Is requires a current controlled voltage negative feedback (emitter resistor). If the base voltage is generated with a sufficiently low impedance voltage divider, the current flowing into the base plays only a minor role.

Comment: Thank you very much! I would have liked to hear this speech from my professors, but unfortunately it didn't happen. Really comprehensive answer, thanks again!

Comment: @LvW Thank you. Since the OP is clearly a newbie I didn't want to delve into Ebers-Moll equations, lest he be confused. What you said is a good complement to my answer, should he need more specific info.

Comment: @KaleM You're welcome. Sadly many universities still teach BJTs in an "old fashion", focusing too much on circuit analysis and much less on design practices and intuition. So circuits tend to be more difficult to grasp for newbies. I suggest getting a copy of the book "The art of Electronics" for more information on electronic design. It's a "monster" book (at 1000+ pages), but it covers everything a designer should know about general-purpose electronics.

Comment: Do you know what changes from one version to another? I found the third version but I saw that they reached the fifth

Comment: @KaleM 5th? Where did you get that number? 3rd edition is the latest and was a 25 years long endeavor, published in 2015. [This is the official website](https://artofelectronics.net/).

Answer (score 3):

You can add some negative feedback with an emitter resistor, so that the output current through R3 and R4 will be determined by the voltage divider R1 and R2. I got an output voltage of 3.06 V with a 2N3904 (hfe=100), 2.87 V with 2N4401 (hfe=300), and 2.43 V with 2SC1845 (hfe=600). So the output voltage remains at about half the supply voltage over a large range of hfe.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fwEIWa.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image: Voltages]